# Could I use gryph-chargers for my Warhammer 40k space marines? And would they fit?

Tags: warhammer-40k, age-of-sigmar, game-lore

When creating a custom space marine chapter i wanted to make something that was a little unique visually. Right now it doesn't really have anything that stands out so I decided to add a fast attack/cavalry like unit to add to my chapters knight like appearance.

I searched through existing Warhammer 40k mounts and found non that fit within my price range since they were pretty costly and the ones that weren't costly weren't what I was looking for visually.

I then broadened my search to the age of sigmar collection and found the vanguard-palladors.

What I wanted to know is, could a space marine fit on top of a gryph-charger from this set? And if so, would it be acceptable lore and game wise. (If I used them I would use the attack bike datasheet)

Answer (score 1):

While 40K and Age of Sigmar are both technically 28mm scale models AoS tends to run a little larger than 40K.

That said the Stormcast models are a very close match to Primaris models in terms of size, so a waist up conversion for Vanguard-Palladors is possible.

Otherwise if you're wanting to use regular marines either the legs will look a little off, or they'll need more heavy conversion.

Comment: Alright thank you, would it be easier if I substitute the gryth-chargers for the gryph hounds set, or would they be too small for space marines to ride. I don't play Sigmar so I don't really know how they would match size wise

Comment: The Gryph-Hounds are a little too small to use for a mount without looking a little comical, although they might work for a Squats conversion